# Trying to find sum of a list in a Jinja2 template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask application where I need to display the total investment by an Investor. There are 3 models namely Fund, Investor and Investments and they are defined as:

```
class Fund(db.Model):
    FundID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    FundName = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    UnitPrice = db.Column(db.Float)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Fund('{self.FundName}', '{self.UnitPrice}')"

class Investor(db.Model):
    InvestorID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    FirstName = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    LastName = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    fund_value = db.relationship('Investment', backref='Investor')
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Investor('{self.InvestorID}','{self.FirstName}')"


class Investment(db.Model):
    InvestmentID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Fund_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('fund.FundID'), nullable=False)
    Investor_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('investor.InvestorID'), nullable=False)
    Units = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    Investment_Value = db.Column(db.Integer)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.Investment_Value}'
```

The route for my investor page is as below:

```
@app.route("/Investors", methods=['GET','POST'])
def Investors():
    Investors = Investor.query.all()
    return render_template('Investors.html', title="List of Investors", investors=Investors)
```

And finally, my template Investors.html is as below:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
        <h1>List of Investors</h1><br/>
        <table>
        <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Total Investment Value</th>
        </tr>
        {% for investor in investors %}        
                <tr>
                  <td><a class="mr-2" href="{{ url_for('update_investor', Investor_ID=investor.InvestorID) }}">{{ investor.FirstName }} {{ investor.LastName }}</a></td>
                  <td>{{ investor.email }}</td>
                  <td>{{ investor.fund_value|sum }}</td>
                </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table><br/>
        <div>
          <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ url_for('create_investor') }}">Add New Investor</a>
        </div>        
{% endblock %}
```

Now, in this template, in the last td, I am trying to find the sum of all the investments for a particular investor and display it, but when I use {{ investor.fund_value|sum }} it gives me the error that "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Investment'". I tried this by running a loop inside my Jinja template but no help. I am quite stuck here for some time since I am new to Flask so any help is appreciated.

Comment: fund_value is a relationship not a column. Are you sure you can make calculations on it? Have you tested that it is numberic column? If all is ok, you have many alternantives, like caclulating sums inside the sl query or in python before the rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take that kind of logic up to the view, or make a class method.

Here's how you could update your view:

```
@app.route("/Investors", methods=['GET','POST'])
def Investors():
    Investors = Investor.query.all()

    invested_sums = {}
    for investor in Investors:
        invested_sums[investor.InvestorID] = 0
        investments_by_investor = Investment.query.filter_by(Investor_ID=investor.InvestorID)
        for investment in investments_by_investor:
            invested_sums[investor.InvestorID] += investment.Investment_Value

    return render_template('Investors.html', title="List of Investors", investors=Investors, invested_sums=invested_sums)
```

Then you can refer to the invested_sums in your template by the InvestorID.

Comment: Agreed. This is 'business' logic. Keep such logic in views, and not in templates, and you'll be happier.

Comment: Agreed as well, this is indeed the clean solution and working as expected. 
But just out of curiosity, don't you think that one line of code in the template was better than this logic in the route. I agree with @DaveW.Smith comment that its the business logic and should be kept in views.